# Creating build in workspace

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

How can I build any of the app in workspace by giving app name or something else.

I have multiple **apps** in **workspace** like below folder structure:-

```
-myworkspace
    --workspace.json
    --build
    --ext
    --App1
    --App2
    --App3
    --.........
```

I can build a particular app by below command:-

```
:~/Desktop/myworksace/App1$ sencha app build
```

But, I want to build any of the app withing the workspace something like below:-

```
:~/Desktop/myworksace$ sencha app build App1
```

How can I achieve this? I am using ExtJS "6.5.0.775".

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will have to change build script.Did you checked related same.

Comment: I was thinking the same but I am not getting what and where to change for the same.